# javascript each toggle class with addEventListener

Tags: javascript

There is a javascript handler; when you click, a contact form pops up to send an email. Everything works but to the first card, on the second card it does not work.

I already tried forEach, but still some kind of mess

Here are the expected result and my current code: https://codepen.io/shkasjon/pen/JjYmgyP

```
( function( $ ) {
    "use strict";

    //let elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll(".as_profile_widget");
    let asBody = $(".as-body-wrap").height();
    const cta = document.querySelector('.as-header');
    const footer = document.querySelector('.as-toaster');
    const arrowIcon = document.querySelector('.arrow-down-close');  

    function setHeight() {
        let asHeight = 0;
        //let asBody = $(".as-body-wrap");
        asHeight = asBody;
    }

    setHeight();
    $(window).resize(setHeight);


    function toggleFooter() {
        footer.classList.toggle('is-open');
        arrowIcon.classList.toggle('open');

        (footer.classList.contains('is-open') ? 
            $('.as-toaster.is-open').css('margin-top', -asBody) : 
            $(footer).css('margin-top', '') 
        );
    }
    //elementsArray.forEach(function(cta) { }); 

    cta.addEventListener('click', toggleFooter);

}( jQuery ) );
```

Comment: You tried for each on what?  Put your current code in your question.  Don't make us go to an off site snippet site to see your code.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: Also as a side note; you're already taking the hit of loading jQuery to your site, but you're using the native selectors in some places and not in others.  That's a code smell.  For consistency, you should stick with one or the other, unless you have a concrete reason not to.

Comment: Please re-read my first comment.  Off site runnable snippets are fine, so long as they are not the only way to see your logic.  The logic in your snippet should also be present in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you have loop over the `.as_profile_widget` elements and find `.as-header` and others **in** that element, in your current code `cta`, `footer` and `arrowIcons` will always be the same

You can do this by using `querySelector` on the element itself

```js
(function( $ ) {
 "use strict";

 let elementsArray = document.querySelectorAll(".as_profile_widget");

 function process(element) {
    const cta = element.querySelector('.as-header');
    const footer = element.querySelector('.as-toaster');
    const arrowIcon = element.querySelector('.arrow-down-close'); 

    // Add event listener and other stuff here
 }
 elementsArray.forEach(process)

})
```

With this `cta` and others will be scoped to your element (card)

(there might be mistakes in the code, and it's far from complete, but you should be able to work from here)

note: as one of the comments points out using Jquery and native methods mixed like this is shaky